# QLabel not updating properly

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I am trying to update QLabels after a process and I used SIGNALS and SLOTS.

Signal:

```
void LayerCountUpdate(int, double, double);
```

Method :

```
LayerCountUpdate(TotalLayers, formatting->GetPrintTime(), formatting->GetResinConsumption());
```

Slot:

```
void ui_prt_settings::UpdateUIInfo(int count, double time, double cost)
{
    _ui->info_LayerCount->setText(QString::number(count));
    _ui->info_volumeValue->setText(QString::number(cost));
    _ui->info_timeEstimate->setText(QDateTime::fromTime_t(time).toUTC().toString("hh:mm:ss"));

    qDebug()<< _ui->info_LayerCount->text();
    qDebug()<< _ui->info_volumeValue->text();
    qDebug()<< _ui->info_timeEstimate->text();
}
```

Supposedly, the label output does not match the one displayed in QDebug. If the expected text on QLabel "infoLayerCount" is **12** it only displays **1**. If I tried other data, it still only displays the 1st digit.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding **adjustSize();** function for the QLabel.